# $k[[t]]$-module structure on coordinate ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, modules, power-series

Let $k$ be a field and $k[[t]]$ the ring of formal power series over $k$. A text that I am reading says:

> Consider the coordinate ring $k[x,y,t]/(x^2+txy)$ with its canonical $k[[t]]$-module structure.

What is the canonical $k[[t]]$-module structure on $k[x,y,t]/(x^2+txy)$? My guess would be $\sum_i a_i t^i.[\sum_l(\sum_{j,k} b_{i,j,k}x^jy^k)t^l]:=[\sum_l(\sum_{j=0}^l a_jc_{l-j})t^l]$, where $c_l=\sum_{j,k} b_{i,j,k}x^jy^k$. But I am not seeing that this expression even makes sense, i.e. that the formal power series $\sum_l(\sum_{j=0}^l a_jc_{l-j})t^l$ has a representative (w.r.t. modding out by the ideal $(x^2+txy)$) in $k[x,y,t]$.

---

The text I am reading is based on [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0705.3719), namely Exercise 3.14 on page 12. See comments below.

Comment: Can you add where you read this to the question? I agree it does not make sense as written in the post - perhaps there's more information in the document this was originally found in.

Comment: @KReiser These are handwritten notes, but they are based on [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0705.3719). It refers to p.12, Exercise 3.14, I think, if that helps.

Comment: With the definitions of the paper, this exercise doesn't make much sense to me. But your question doesn't fit to the exercise either... The exercise talks about k[x,y] modulo x^2 as the base.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg My question fits to the exercise with $A=k[x,y]/(x^2)$, $R=k[[t]]$, $B=k[x,y,t]/(x^2+txy)$. The exercise asks about a deformation of $A$ over $R$. Deformations over $k[[t]]$ are called formal deformations, or am I missing sth?

Comment: The exercise further implictly asks whether the $R$-module $B$ is free (see page 11: "In this note we assume that $B$ is a free $R$-module.")

Comment: It is misprint. The right formula is $$k[x,y][[t]]/(x^2+txy)$$